# Using name as secondary index

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

I want to save name in table, and to search by it. It doesn't seems that it is possible to have secondary index with type name for some reason. I would like also to pass name in function and to have require_auth() on that name parameter. So the question would be, can i somehow convert that name to uint64_t so I can store it and have index on it?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the functionality that the multi index was based around.

To get the name, simple add `.value` to your key on return:

```
uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value;} // key.VALUE
```

---

In the tutorial, they actually use a uint64_t for the secondary index.  [That's all `eosio::name` is under the hood, a uint64_t](https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/structeosio_1_1name.html).  Granted they use it to represent an age by a number, but it's still the same type nonetheless.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/secondary-indices

```
uint64_t age;
uint64_t get_secondary_1() const { return age;} // secondary index

typedef eosio::multi_index<"people"_n, person, 
indexed_by<"byage"_n, const_mem_fun<person, uint64_t, &person::get_secondary_1>>
  > address_index;
```

---

In [this tutorial](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/data-persistence), you can see the primary index is indeed an eosio::name type:

```
struct person {
 name key;
 std::string first_name;
 std::string last_name;
 std::string street;
 std::string city;
 std::string state;

 uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value;}
};
```

Comment: i was missing this "conversion" between name and uint64_t, by using .value! Thanks for pointing me to right direction

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have added that.  Thank you for reminding me!